# jQuery UI resizable handle sticks to original position after scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a resizable which is also scrollable (simple overflow:scroll, no plugin). When scrolling, the bottom handle sticks to it's original position, scrolling up with the rest of the text, instead of sticking to the bottom.

Tried adding children etc., also searched google and here.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: 
Here is the code (using  jquery 2.1.3, and jquery-ui 1.11.4):

javascript:

```
 $("#slide-panel-container").resizable({
   handles: 's'
 });

 $("#info-window").resizable({
   handles: 'e'
 });
```

css:

```
.frontControllers {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 342px;
}
#slide-panel-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.ui-resizable-handle {
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="info-window" class="container-fluid form-group frontControllers">
    <div id="info-sum-container" class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>Flight Unlimited</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="info-full" class="collapse row side-outer-container">
      <div id="slide-panel-container" class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Flight Unlimited is a 1995 flight simulator video game developed and published by Looking Glass Technologies. It allows the player to pilot reproductions of five aircraft and to perform aerobatic stunts. A virtual instructor teaches basic and
            advanced flight techniques, such as Immelmann turns (diagram pictured) and Lomcevak tumbles...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am adding a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jennyabr/zp1hymd2/

To see the problem you need to resize the div with the buttom handle and then scroll down, you will see that the handle is going up with the text, like so: [image: the scrolling resizing problem]

Comment: Can you show your code or make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Are you still working on this?